# How to make combination of keys unique in mongokit document?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongokit

Database structure looks like this.

```py
from mongokit import Document

class FlashscoreNameMap(Document):
    structure = {
        "flashscore_name": basestring,
        "translated_name": basestring,
        "player_id": basestring,
        "timestamp": float
    }
    default_values = {
        "translated_name": '',
        "player_id": ''
    }
    indexes = [
    # How do I declare validation rules here? 
    ]
    use_dot_notation = True
```

Validation Rules to be enforced

1. `player_id` can be `''` empty string, or else it should be `unique`. I've heard the term `sparse` for this. (It need not be unique if it is empty string. This is important.)
2. Combination of `flashscore_name` and `player_id` should be unique.

Any help is appreciated. In case of duplicates, I want to update value of `translated_name`.